# matlab: To find the multiplier which reduces the standard deviation between two series

Tags: matlab

i want to find the value of C such that standard deviation of A-B*C is minimum using matlab (A & B are vectors) where as C would be a scalar. Any ideas ?

Comment: Do you have the [Optimization Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/products/optimization/) installed? If so, you should read about it [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/)...

Answer (score 6):

This isn't a programming problem, it's a math problem. You want to find `c` such that

```
Var(A - c * B)
```

is minimized. But

```
Var(A - c*B) = Var(A) - 2 * c * Cov(A,B) + c^2 * Var(B)
```

Differentiating and setting to zero

```
-2 * Cov(A,B) + 2 * c * Var(B) = 0
```

which implies

```
c = Cov(A,B) / Var(B)
```

You can achieve this in Matlab with

```
M     = cov(A, B); # Now M = [varA, covAB; covAB, varB]
covAB = M(1,2);
varB  = M(2,2);
c     = covAB / varB;
```

Comment: Very nice, it's always good to think about what problem needs to be solved rather than trying to solve it immediately. Technical note: second order derivative is `2*var(B)` This is nonnegative and thus it is guaranteed to be a minimum.

Answer (score 0):

Following @EitanT's advice, try:

```
Ctry = 1.5; % define trial parameter first
Copt = fminsearch(@(x) sum((A-B*x).^2),Ctry)
```

**edit**

Note that in the above I assumed you wanted to minimize the vector norm, but following commentaries it is evident that you want to minimize the std dev of samples in array (A-B*x), in which case try

```
Ctry = 1.5; % define trial parameter first
Copt = fminsearch(@(x) var(A-B*x),Ctry)
```

If you are performing columnwise substraction of vector B from A, you can do as follows:

```
A=rand(900,100); B=randn(900,1); % example

Ctry = 1.5; % define parameter first
B = repmat(B,size(A,2),1);
Copt = fminsearch(@(x) var(A(:)-B*x),Ctry)
Eopt=var(A(:)-B*Copt)
```

@Luis Mendo suggests

```
nA = numel(A);
Copt = fminsearch(@(x) sum((A(:)-B*x).^2)-sum(A(:)-B*x)^2/nA,Ctry)
```

This is a little faster on my system.

Also, as with all minimization problems, it helps if you have a good starting estimate.

**Edit**
It's worth noting that the two methods find points that differ in the second significant figure, which raises the question which is more accurate. <-- just an issue that can be fixed with optimset

Comment: `sum().^2` is not variance (only if mean is zero)

Comment: @Luis Mendo Look at it again, I think it's right...

Comment: Just use `fminsearch(@(x) var(A-B*x),Ctry)`, the current one is probably not right, and at least this one will be easier to read.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin Try `edit var` and compare to my code...

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin Please explain "probably" in "probably" is not right. Have you tried evaluating the proposed answer??

Comment: @Luis Mendo Please read the OP question again. Thanks.

Comment: Should i not use std(A-B*x) ??

Comment: @SameerBhatt I did not think about the command, but minimizing the variance is the same as minimizing the standard deviation, so that will be fine.

Comment: @TryHard I just see that they are not the same `y=1:10;sum(y.^2),var(y),std(y)` I don't know whether it is a monotone transformation, in that case it would of course be correct.

Comment: @Sameer Bhatt The optimum value of C you are looking for will minimize: std dev, variance, and sum((A-B*x).^2). The last one is the fastest of the three to compute...

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin He's trying to minimize the function: it's the same problem worded differently...

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin as far as I understand the OP wants to minimize the norm 2 of (A-B*C)

Comment: @TryHard I still think that `sum((A-B*x).^2)` is not the same as variance. The difference is `mean(A-B*x)^2`, which is _not_ independent of `x`

Comment: @TryHard Why the norm 2? The question clearly specifies "the standard deviation". The variance will do, but not the norm 2, or the mean of squares

Comment: @Luis Mendo Please try edit var and compare to my code...

Comment: @Luis Mendo norm(X,2) is std dev. `doc norm`

Comment: @TryHard Sorry, I don't have the Optimization Toolbox. But look at this example: A = 1:5; B = 2:6. Then std(A-B*1) is 0, and thus c=1 minimizes std (or var). Now, sum((A-B*1).^2) is 5, whereas sum((A-B*.8).^2) is 0.6. So minimizing std is _not_ the same as minimizing sum of squares

Comment: @TryHard norm(X,2) is _not_ std dev! It does not subtract mean, which std does!

Comment: @TryHard I tried your code with my example. It gives Copt = 0.778. Changing to var gives 1.0. This is what I meant in my previous comment

Comment: @LuisMendo Your calcs are right. I took a different interpretation of the question, assuming the interest was to minimize the vector norm.

Comment: I'll add that to my answer, thanks for your (insistent) comments :)

Comment: @TryHard No problem. You've been hard to convince :-D

Comment: @TryHard Regarding your edit: you say "following commentaries it is evident that you want to minimize the std dev". But the _question_ says "I want to find the value of C such that _standard deviation_ of A-B*C is minimum"

Comment: is there a faster way. Matrix A is a 900*100 matrix and i want to and B is a 900*1. and the problem remains the same, min the std deviation between the two ! it seems to be taking ages !

Comment: @LuisMendo and I should have read `var` more carefully, as you correctly state it subtracts the mean... ouch!

Comment: @SameerBhatt On my computer, this seems to be much faster than `var` or `std`. Try it and tell us: `Copt = fminsearch(@(x) sum((A-B*x).^2)-sum(A-B*x)^2/length(A),Ctry)`

Comment: @SameerBhatt You could save a little more time by precomputing `len=length(A)` and then using `Copt = fminsearch(@(x) sum((A-B*x).^2)-sum(A-B*x)^2/len,Ctry)`